# Get Reference to SceneKit Catalog Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit

I must be missing something simple - I'm trying to iterate through the
files in an .scnassets folder but can't seem to get a reference to the
folder/catalog.

Here's the organizer:

[image]

Models.scnassets contains one file. I tried this:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let docsURL = urls.first
let assetFolderPath = docsURL?.appendingPathComponent("Models.scnassets").path
```

And I tried this and several other variants:

```
let modelPathString = "ARAds/Models.scnassets"
```

Then I attempted to count the files with both of the above paths:

```
    do {
        let modelPathDirectoryFiles = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: assetFolderPath!)
        //or modelPathString
        print(modelPathDirectoryFiles.count)
    } catch {
        print("error getting list of files")
    }
```

I get the error message in all cases.
I assume there must be some special way to get a reference to a SceneKit
Catalog but I have not been able to find that in the Apple docs nor SO.
Any guidance would be appreciated. iOS 11.4 Xcode 10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've pointed me in a better direction, but I can already get the scn and make a node if I know the name. What I really want to do is populate a tableview with the options that are available - so I need to find the current list of scene files.

I think this will work:

```
let subdir = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.appendingPathComponent("Models.scnassets").path

do {
    let modelPathDirectoryFiles = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: subdir)
    print(modelPathDirectoryFiles.count) //this works
    //then do my thing with the array
} catch {
    print("error getting list of files")
}
```

This seems to work, whether I move the folder or not.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, the first thing I see, is that you are referencing the `Documents Directory` which isn't actually where your folder is.

`The Documents Directory` is a folder on your actual device where you might save user data or other files which can be accessed at a latter date (for example via iTunes Sharing).

If you move your `Models.scnassets` folder under the yellow `ArAds` folder you should be able to access your content like so:

```
let myModelToLocate = SCNScene(named: "Models.scnassets/Phone_01.scn")
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: `>:/` I had no idea I had to do the nested access